# ArcGIS Pro Web Tool User-Defined Input Data

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-enterprise

I cannot find how to set my parameter as user defined. When I go to Share as Webtool -> content -> edit symbol on the right, the parameter is fixed to constant there.

Any ideas ? It's a folder path the user needs to put in.

Comment: BIG CAUTION to anyone reading this Q/A:  Having the consumer of a GP Service input a string that represents a folder is generally not a good solution. This folder must exist either on the server, or point to a shared drive the server has access too. This workflow generally should be re-evaluated. It's ok to upload/send data to the server, but having server look at a path and find data sets a user up to fail more often than not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that folders are always constant. Changing the parameter type to string solved the problem-